# How to use Coldbox's event.setValue to set data on the prc

Tags: coldfusion, coldbox

In Coldbox the event object sports a setValue function.  You pass it a key and value and it will set the value for that key on the rc.  Is there a way to tell setValue to operate on the prc instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
event.setValue(name="myVar", private=true);
```

or

```
<cfset event.setValue(name="myVar", private=true) />
```

Comment: After I asked the question I had the bright idea to look in the code :S  There it was.

Answer (score 3):

I would also recommend you talk directly to the passed in collection structures.  Working with structures in ColdFusion is much much faster than method calls